# Dein options to only load plugin if dependent program found

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-managers

I'm trying to set up Dein to load the [gen_tags](https://github.com/jsfaint/gen_tags.vim) plugin. However, if Universal/Exuberant Ctags or GNU Global aren't found on the path, I get the following error message when trying to start `nvim`:

> ctags not found
>   gen_tags.vim need ctags to generate tags
>   GNU Global not found
>   gen_gtags.vim need GNU Global
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

Pressing enter does nothing. Sometimes I can get the prompt back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Sometimes it locks up and I have to crash the shell. I haven't found what controls that behavior yet. If `ctags` and `global` are on the `$PATH`, everything works great.

But ideally I would like Dein to only attempt to load the plugin if `ctags` or `global` are available so I don't encounter this error message when setting up a new machine.

Here are three different options that I've tried:

```
call dein#add('jsfaint/gen_tags.vim', { 'depends': ['ctags', 'global']})             "tag maintainer
call dein#add('jsfaint/gen_tags.vim', { 'on_cmd': ['ctags', 'global']})             "tag maintainer
call dein#add('jsfaint/gen_tags.vim', { 'on_if': 'empty(glob($VIM."/exe/ctags"))'})             "tag maintainer
```

What are the correct options to pass to Dein to conditionally load this plugin?

I'm doing this on Windows 10 and PowerShell with neovim. I haven't tried this on a Linux system yet but eventually I would like this to work cross platform.

---

I've tried Christian's solution as well as another Dein option. Both fail to load the plugin when it is first added to the path and only `nvim` is run. Launching `nvim-qt` will load the plugin and both will load the plugin on subsequent launches. Occasionally (but not reliably) using the Dein option will cause the error noted above when the programs are not in the path.

**NOTE: when I say "Open" or "Close" below, I mean all associated windows. There are 3 or 4 windows to go through to change the path and leaving some open or leaving PowerShell open seems to change the behavior.*

### To reproduce:

- Remove programs from path
- Close all path related windows
- Open PowerShell
- Test `ctags` and `global` to make sure they are *not* executable
- Run `nvim` from PowerShell
- Using: `if executable('ctags') || executable('global')`

  - No error
- Using dein options: `{ 'if': 'executable("ctags") || executable("global")' })`

  - Sometimes causes an error that requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to get back to prompt
  - Sometimes no error
- If no error, test that `:GenCtags` and `:GenGTAGS` are *not* available
- Close `nvim` and `PowerShell`
- Add programs back to path
- Open PowerShell
- Test `ctags` and `global` to make sure they *are* executable
- Using: `if executable('ctags') || executable('global')`

  - `:GenCtags` and `:GenGTAGS` are *not* available
- Using dein options: `{ 'if': 'executable("ctags") || executable("global")' })`

  - `:GenCtags` and `:GenGTAGS` are *not* available
- Close `nvim` and PowerShell

  - These can be closed and reopened many times with the same result
- Open `nvim-qt` using Cortana
- Test that `:GenCtags` and `:GenGTAGS` *are* available
- Plugin will be loaded from now on in both `nvim` and `nvim-qt`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
if executable('ctags') || executable('global')
    call dein#add('...')
endif
```

Comment: That's what I was doing when I was using Vundle. But I was under the impression that Dein could handle this for me. In [this issue](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim/issues/74) they use Dein to install `fzf` and then check for it before loading the `fzf` plugin. That's what I'm going for.

Comment: Why would you use a feature, that makes you depend on a plugin rather than using something which you can independently of any plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you asking why am I using external programs like `ctags` and `global`? Because they make my life easier. But I don't want to depend on them. I want my plugin manager to only load the plugin if the feature exists. Or are you asking why use a feature of Dein rather than basic vimscript? What's the point of using plugins at all if I'm not going to make use of their features? I'm depending on one plugin, my plugin manager, to manage my plugins and only load those that the underlying system supports.

Comment: No I am asking why would you depend on a solution specific to dein, when you can use the same thing with any plugin manager you might happen to use in the future?

Comment: Why use a plugin at all if you're not going to make use of its features? Dein is just vimscript that loads more vimscript. Why not write every command and function I need myself and not depend on anybody? We could wax philosophical all day about this. But the point is that Dein has many much more powerful and complex options but I cannot get this simple example to work reliably. I'm trying to figure out if it's my dot file, nvim/Win10/PS combo, or Dein that's the problem.

Comment: FWIW, the option I've had the most success with has the same character count as your answer. And I can't even call it syntactic sugar because I find yours to be more readable. But they both fail to load the plugin on first run. I'm going to update the question with reproduction steps.

Comment: it is debatable. But I see no sense in inventing support for a feature that is basically useless and as you can see, not many can help with that. So I would for clarity always use the basic vimscript feature. And yes, I tend to avoid plugins for functionality that can be easily done with a couple of vimscript lines.

Comment: The use of plugins is debatable. However that's an opinion based discussion which is frowned upon on SE and not what I'm asking regardless. I think I've shown that Dein's syntax is just an abstraction for the same thing you are suggesting and that they both fail in very similar ways. I'm not asking you to "invent support for a useless feature". I'm asking, regardless of Dein's syntax or basic vimscript syntax, can you reproduce the failure I'm seeing and do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure why you think the `executable()` fails. That is the supported syntax for that particular feature of Vim. If you want support for a specific feature, you should better ask the plugin author. And no, you have not shown, why dein's syntax is an abstraction of anything. If any, it's a specilisation of something that can be easily achieved using the normal Vim script functions.

Comment: Well, I thought my reproduction steps clearly showed that, using the supported syntax, the code inside the `if` fails to execute when the path is first updated. I would like to know if anyone else is able to reproduce this specific bug. But you seem more interested in giving sermons on your opinion of the evils of plugins. So I will seek help elsewhere. Thank you for your time.